# Meaning of "support" in terms of computer science

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I've seen the word "support" used in various contexts but despite a lot of googling I've only been able to find a single definition so far for computer science, specifically regarding machine learning (support vectors, in support vector machines). This isn't necessarily the specific context I'm trying to understand.

My particular question has to do with a lecture slide I'm reading -- it's something about using the hough transform for circle-detection (computer vision) and somewhere on this slide it says "...In this procedure for each (x,y,r) we draw the corresponding circle in the image and compute its support."

What are other possible meanings of the word "support" in the context of computer science?

Comment: It's a generic term. There are going to be *so many* definitions across CS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [slide you are referring to](http://www.cs.illinois.edu/~slazebni/spring11/lec10_hough.pptx) puts the word "support" in quotes:

## Hough transform for circles

- Conceptually equivalent procedure: for each (x,y,r), draw the corresponding circle in the image and compute its “support”

The context of the lecture is "voting schemes" for machine vision.  The term "support" doesn't appear to be used as a technical term, but rather refers to voting, where a high vote total indicates "support" for a candidate or position.

Comment: okay that definitely makes more sense now